# Is possible to create a mysql database at execution time in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

For example, if I have a form with an input field where I type the database name and I click submit button to create a mysql database with the name from the field, is possible?

Comment: yes, if whatever user your node code logs into mysql with has the appropriate privileges granted. a `create` query is a query like any other, really...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with node-mysql or with a query builder like knex